# How to append characters to an SVG text element without changing its textContent value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to append characters to an SVG text element which are separate from the text element's text content value.  The characters need to come in front of the text element, and look like they are part of the word, e.g. if this were my tag,

```
<text ...>bar</text>
```

I would then 'append' "foo" to the front of it, such that when its displayed in the browser users see:

```
foobar
```

but in reality the text content of the element is still just "bar."

I've tried using the CSS ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, but these appear to have no effect:

```
svg text::before
{
  content: "foo"
}
```

However, they work perfectly fine for non-SVG elements:

```
li::before
{
  content: "foo"
}
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to allow zero-spacing between SVG text elements?  e.g.

```
<text class="something" text-anchor="end" dy=".5ex" y="110.25" x="-15">foo</text>
<text style="display:block; float:left; padding: 1px;" class="something-else" text-anchor="end" dy=".5ex" y="110.25" x="-15" font-family="FontAwesome">bar</text>
```

appears such that "foo" is stacked directly on top of "bar."  I can change the x coordinate by eyeballing it, but this is really inconvenient, as I have no control over the width of either svg text element content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a text/tspan combination E.g.

```
<text><tspan>foo</tspan>bar</text>
```

or

```
<text>foo<tspan>bar</tspan></text>
```

This would allow you to style the foo and bar differently which seems to be what you want.

You can write

```
tspan = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
text.appendChild(tspan);
```

to add a tspan to a text element (assuming you've got your text element in the variable called text).

Getting the text content of the tspan just gets the tspan text content for me as one would expect. E.g.

```js
alert(document.getElementById("tspan").textContent);
```

```html
<svg><text>foo<tspan id="tspan">bar</tspan></text><svg>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add this dynamically to an existing SVG text element or use CSS?

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like if I access the `<tspan/>` text content, it actually returns the text content of the parent `<text/>` tag.

Comment: You can't add additional content to SVG via CSS but you can with javascript as I've shown in the updated answer. Getting the `<tspan/>` text content only gets what I expect when I run it. I've also updated my answer to show that. If you've more questions it's probably best to ask them separately though.