# Psuedo after on svg text element possible?

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to add text in psuedo after on svg text element?

```
<text 
    class="nv-axislabel" 
    text-anchor="middle" 
    y="36" 
    x="279.5" 
    style="opacity: 1;">Time (ms)
</text>
```

I would like to have something that would add text and give smaller font size to that text. I have to do this because I don't have access to this text element.

```
.nv-axislabel::after {
    content: "Trying to add";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: **Highly** Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832600/how-to-append-characters-to-an-svg-text-element-without-changing-its-textcontent

Comment: Not possible with SVG 1.1.  It *may* be allowed for the upcoming SVG 2.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I have put in a request to close this as the related question does answer this. Thank you